# How can I avoid getting the message Solve::ratnz?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, warning-messages

My function is

```
(* condição para o valor de b0 *)

σ = 0.6 ;

minroot[g_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{rts, r}, 
    rts = r /. 
      Solve[1 - (b/r)^2 - 
        g^-2*(2/15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 
              9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8 - 
                 1/(r + 1)^8)) - σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 
              1/(r + 1)^3 - 3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2))) == 
       0, r];
    rts = Select[rts, With[{nval = N[#, 100]}, Im[nval] == 0 && nval > 0] &]; 
    Max[rts]];

rootmin[g_?NumberQ] := 
  Module[{Rrmts, b}, 
    Rrmts = b /. 
      FindRoot[Re[aA[g, b, 5]] == 0, {b, 1, 2}, Method -> "Brent"]; 
   Rrmts];

(* angulo de espalhamento *)
aA[g_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, i_] := 
  Pi - 2 b  NIntegrate[
     1/(r^2*Sqrt[
         1 - (b/r)^2 - 
          g^-2*(2/15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 
                9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8 - 
                   1/(r + 1)^8)) - σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 
                1/(r + 1)^3 - 
                3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2)))]), {r, 
      minroot[g, b], Infinity}, 
     Exclusions -> {r^2*
         Sqrt[1 - (b/r)^2 - 
           g^-2*(2/
               15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 
                 9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8 - 
                    1/(r + 1)^8)) - σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 
                 1/(r + 1)^3 - 
                 3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2)))] == 0}, 
     MaxRecursion -> i, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
```

When I evaluate

```
rootmin[0.3]
```

I get

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

but when I evaluate

```
rootmin[0.4]
```

> ```
> 1.95804
> ```

I still get some errors, but I get a result.

Why? I want to evaluate `rootmin[0.1]`, for example, and I can't.

Comment: I get a bunch of different errors as well: `NIntegrate::inumr`, `FindRoot::nlnum` etc. Also, in the definition `aA`, you use `minroot[g,b]`; Is it the same as `rootmin[g,b]`?

Comment: @Mahdi, minroot[g,b] is a value of r , and rootmin[g,b] is a value of b , so they are differents ... do you have an ideia of all this errrors ?

Comment: Please edit the question and give a definition for your function `minroot`.

Comment: @m_goldberg , sorry ... now its ok ... any ideas ?

Comment: I hope this question will be reopened. Now that you have supplied a definition for `minroot`, it is pretty clear what your problem is, and I have an answer I would like to post.

Comment: The reopen votes aren't coming as fast as I would like. In short, the reason you not getting results for `rootmin[.3]` is that `Re[aA[.3, b, 5]] == 0` has no real roots for `b` in the interval `[1, 2]`. Further there are no real roots in that interval for `g` in `[0, 3.6]`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, i copy your code , but there is not working, all my rootmin values gives the same 1.5708, no matter g value ... and there is an error  Inappropriate parameter: MaxRecursion -> i. >>  ...  and the aA values gives the same too for all values of g and b ... can you test again and tell me later ? thanks

Comment: @m_goldberg, give this error too ..   The integrand 1/(r^2 Sqrt[1-b^2/r^2-((13122 \
(Power[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]))/9765625-27/125 \
(Power[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]))/g^2]) has evaluated to \
non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with \
boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.` +minroot[g,b]}}. >>

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo in the code I posted. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: There were a pair of parentheses missing from the definition of `aA`. I have edited my answer below to fix that. Copy the repaired definition of `aA` and try using it.

Comment: @m_goldberg if i increase the interval to [1,10] for example, it will give me the same results ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your most recent question, but why don't you try it and see what happens. When I set he interval for `b` to be [1, 10] , I get the same results for `rootmin` for those values of `g` that gave values in the range [1, 2], but I also was able to get values of `rootmin` at least down to `g = 0.05`. I didn't try any smaller values of `g`,

Comment: @m_goldberg , why cant i find a value only for minroot ? try to put minroot[10,10] and will give  \[Sqrt]Root[
  24414062500 - 219966549985 #1 + 881077612635 #1^2 - 
    2059507857936 #1^3 + 3096595115670 #1^4 - 3106870312500 #1^5 + 
    2081517656250 #1^6 - 899409843750 #1^7 + 228515625000 #1^8 - 
    26611328125 #1^9 + 244140625 #1^10 &, 2]

Comment: Please do not bring up more and more issues in comments. This site is not a discussion forum. I have given your problem a lot of time;I do not more time to give to it.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I did was to rationalizing all calculations, starting with the defintion of `σ` and `minroot`. This stops the `Solve::ratnz` messages. I also made some other improvements to `minroot`.

```
σ = 6/10;

minroot[gg_?NumericQ, bb_?NumericQ] :=
  Module[{b, g, rts, r},
    b = Rationalize[bb, 0];
    g = Rationalize[gg, 0];
    rts = r /.
      Solve[
        1 - (b/r)^2 -
          g^-2*(2/15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 -
            9/(8 r) (1/(r - 1)^8 - 1/(r + 1)^8)) - σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 -
              1/(r + 1)^3 - 3/(2 r) (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2))) == 0,
        r];
    Max[Select[rts, Im[#] == 0 && # > 0 &]]]
```

The definition of `aA` is more or less untouched.

```
aA[g_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, i_] :=
  (Pi - 2 b
    NIntegrate[
      1/(r^2* Sqrt[
        1 - (b/r)^2 -
         g^(-2)*
           (2/15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 9/(8 r) *
              (1/(r - 1)^8 - 1/(r + 1)^8)) -
            σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 -1/(r + 1)^3 -3/(2 r) *
              (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2)))]),
      {r, minroot[g, b], ∞},
      Exclusions ->
        {r^2*Sqrt[1 - (b/r)^2 -
          g^(-2)*
            (2/15*σ^9 (1/(r - 1)^9 - 1/(r + 1)^9 - 9/(8 r) *
              (1/(r - 1)^8 - 1/(r + 1)^8)) -
            σ^3 (1/(r - 1)^3 - 1/(r + 1)^3 - 3/(2 r) *
              (1/(r - 1)^2 - 1/(r + 1)^2)))] == 0},
    MaxRecursion -> i,
    Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}])
```

A plot of `aA` over the interval `[1, 2]` for several values of `g` shows the problem with small values of `g`.

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[aA[#, b, 5]]& /@ #], {b, 1, 2},
  PlotPoints -> 5,
  PlotRange -> {-.25, 2.25},
  PlotLegends -> Evaluate[( Style[Row[{"g = ", #}], 12]&) /@ #],
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> Medium]&[{.1, .3, .36, .4}]
```

[image: plots]

We now know why `rootmin` fails for `g < .36116`; however, using the version of `minroot` shown above, `rootmin` produces no messages for values of `g >= .36116`. I do recommend simplifying it as shown below.

```
rootmin[g_?NumberQ] :=
  Module[{b},
    b /. FindRoot[Re[aA[g, b, 5]] == 0, {b, 1, 2}, Method -> "Brent"]]
```

Now we look at

```
rootmin[.36116]
```

> ```
> 2.
> ```

It is the critical point because it is where the zero of the real part of `aA` falls right at the end of the interval `[1, 2]`.